# enablePassThrough not available for selenium server 3.9.1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I was using selenium server 3.7.1 for my test setup using this command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -enablePassThrough false
```

But trying to update to 3.9.1, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException:
Was passed main parameter '-enablePassThrough' but no main parameter
was defined in your arg class
```

Meaning `enablePassThrough` is not available in the latest version of selenium? Why? What other option or setup is available instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **`enablePassThrough`**

**`enablePassThrough`** mode was introduced for the first time in [*Selenium Client v3.5.0*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) . *enablePassThrough* allowed a connection from your test's RemoteWebDriver, through the Grid Hub, to a Grid Node, and down to a DriverService and then to the browser to use the same WebDriver protocol (the Json Wire Protocol or the W3C one) end to end without translation.

*enablePassThrough* mode could have been disabled by starting the standalone server or Grid node with the argument `-enablePassThrough false`

With the release and availability of [*Selenium Client v3.9.0*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) all **HTTP communication** was switched to **OkHttp**. Though you can still change the version  back to the Apache HttpClient by setting the `webdriver.http.factory` system property to `apache`.

Simultanously support for the **passthrough** mode for the server was **dropped**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know of any instructions to get 3.9.x to work with geckodriver?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt I am at the fag end of my work with 3.8.1 binaries. I will be switching to v3.9.x shortly. The release notes doesn't throws any light on any major issue. If you come across any specific issue raise a question with the exact Manual Step, we will help you out for sure.

Comment: Is "system property" something specific for Java? I'm using PHP for my tests.

Comment: Am getting same error message after going to 3.9 I was on 3.1 before. BUT i'm not specifying a -enablepasssthrough or a -role arg at all. Can someone explain what those parameters accomplish? I's starting the server with a driver path, and `-host 172.22.0.2 -port 4444` .

Comment: I added `-role webdriver` to my args, and now 3.9 appears to be happily working. I only wish there were canonical documentation around to save time.

Comment: @ConradB Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)