# How to add Options through Facebook/php-webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, facebook-php-webdriver, php-webdriver

I'm seeking to add options to an instance of Facebook/php-webdriver.

This works to get the initial options:

```
$options = \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
```

Now I'd like to add additional options:

```
$options->setCapability("enablePassThrough", FALSE);
$options->setCapability("no-sandbox", TRUE);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Call to undefined function setCapability()
```

I've tried a few approaches, but haven't yet found out how to do it.

What is the correct way to add options to an instance of Facebook/php-webdriver?

Answer (score 5):

### `setCapability()`

[**`setCapability()`**](https://hotexamples.com/examples/facebook.webdriver.remote/DesiredCapabilities/setCapability/php-desiredcapabilities-setcapability-method-examples.html) method configures the *WebDriver* instance with the *capabilities* through an instance of *DesiredCapabilities()* as follows:

```
public function testShouldProvideAccessToCapabilitiesUsingSettersAndGetters()
{
    $capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // generic capability setter
    $capabilities->setCapability('custom', 1337);
    // specific setters
    $capabilities->setBrowserName(WebDriverBrowserType::CHROME);
    $capabilities->setPlatform(WebDriverPlatform::LINUX);
    $capabilities->setVersion(333);
    $this->assertSame(1337, $capabilities->getCapability('custom'));
    $this->assertSame(WebDriverBrowserType::CHROME, $capabilities->getBrowserName());
    $this->assertSame(WebDriverPlatform::LINUX, $capabilities->getPlatform());
    $this->assertSame(333, $capabilities->getVersion());
}
```

---

### `--no-sandbox`

[**`-no-sandbox`**](https://hotexamples.com/examples/facebook.webdriver.remote/DesiredCapabilities/chrome/php-desiredcapabilities-chrome-method-examples.html) *argument* can be added through instance of `ChromeOptions()` and further can be added to the instance of *DesiredCapabilities()* as follows:

```
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(array('--no-sandbox'));
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
```

---

### enablePassThrough

**`enablePassThrough`** mode was introduced for the first time in [*Selenium Client v3.5.0*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) . *enablePassThrough* allowed a connection from your test's RemoteWebDriver, through the Grid Hub, to a Grid Node, and down to a DriverService and then to the browser to use the same WebDriver protocol (the Json Wire Protocol or the W3C one) end to end without translation.

*enablePassThrough* mode could have been disabled by starting the standalone server or Grid node with the argument `-enablePassThrough false`

With the release and availability of [*Selenium Client v3.9.0*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) all **HTTP communication** was switched to **OkHttp**. Though you can still change the version  back to the Apache HttpClient by setting the `webdriver.http.factory` system property to `apache`.

Simultanously support for the **passthrough** mode for the server was **dropped**.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [enablePassThrough not available for selenium server 3.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682811/enablepassthrough-not-available-for-selenium-server-3-9-1)

Comment: Could you provide additional detail? On `$options = new ChromeOptions();` I am getting:  `Message: Class 'ChromeOptions' not found`.  If I do:  `$options = \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $options->addArguments(array('--no-sandbox'));`  I get the message, `Call to undefined method Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::addArguments()`.

Comment: @VikR Honestly I am not that regular with facebook-php-driver but I have provided the hyperlink for each of the topics for your reference. Let me know if you are looking for more documentation.

Comment: I did see the link for the `SetCapability` docs yesterday. It has the code you note, but on my system throws the errors I am seeing. So I still need an answer regarding how to do this. At the same time, I have upvoted your response. Thanks for this good info!

Comment: @VikR Can you add your observations within the main question so I can lookout exactly to what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB for asking and for the great info you previously posted! I found the correct syntax and have posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works on my system:

```
    $options = new \Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions();
    $options->addArguments(array('--no-sandbox'));
    $capabilities = \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
    $capabilities->setCapability(\Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
    $seleniumDriver = \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create(
        $host,
        $capabilities,
        5000
    );
```

Comment: I don't see any significant change in your code other than duplicating the absolute path of the _Class_ i.e. **`new ChromeOptions()`** being changed to `new \Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions()` and so on.

Answer (score -2):

```
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(array('--no-sandbox'));
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
```

Comment: This answer is *exactly* the same as a section of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52967085/) to this question. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27757716)